# Password box won't show up during login

Tags: xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I'm a developer with Bitglass working on the product integration of our CASB and Evernote. When proxying via our CASB, on the login page (https://www.evernote.com/Login.action), after typing in the username and clicking continue, the password box won't show up. In the developers console, I noticed an XHR to https://www.evernote.com/Login.action results in a 418 response. After some debugging, I've noticed that your server would only accept the http request header, x-requested-with, but not X-Requested-With. As http headers aren't case sensitive, can the part of your server handling this request be modified to support the upper case version of the header as well?